# PHP Error in wordpress - Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in plugins/Ultimate_VC_Addons/.. line 343

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am facing an issue with my WordPress site with the following notice and it has broking a huge part of my site.

I am getting this message at the homepage:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /www/wp-content/plugins/Ultimate_VC_Addons/modules/ultimate_parallax.php on line 343

```php
foreach ($layer_image as $key=>$value) {
   $bg_imgs[]=$layer_image[$key][0];  //line 343
}
```

Have been reading through many cases but not really clear why this happens.
Any one who can assist I am new to php.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I recently got also this error message in `config.php` after upgrading to **PHP 8.0**. Error message disappeared after **downgrading to PHP 7.4**.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's because:

- Incompatible of `Ultimate VC Addons` with PHP version on the server.
- Incompatible of `Ultimate VC Addons` with WordPress.
- Incompatible of `Ultimate VC Addons` with other plugins.
- The data in the `Ultimate parallax` module is incorrect.

**There is something you can try if you are new to PHP:**

- Check the data you are added in `Ultimate parallax`
- Remove that module and add again
- Update `Ultimate VC Addons` to the latest version, also check the version of WordPress if it is too old.
- Contact the `Ultimate VC Addons` plugin provider.